# How to Follow Object When Moving?

Tags: 3d-view

I am using blender 2.83 and I know how to use Numpad Period to find the selected object, but I have a object moving and when I press play my viewport camera just sits there. How do I follow the object in the viewport when it’s moving? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Press the N key, and in the view tab, press lock to object.[image]