# How do you move an object and have it stay in focus in the viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode, object-mode

Say that you have to move an object, vertex, vertices, face, etc in your viewport and you need to move it to a location out of the field of view in the viewport.  What keys are used to be able to move an object and have the viewport stay focused on the thing you are moving as you are moving it? What is the shortcut/setup to be able to do that? Just to clarify, when moving whatever your moving, I would like to move it in one continuous move to a location that is off my viewport and do it accurately.  If I start to move an object and then I have to move it further than my viewport can currently display.  Not using the Numpad .(period) shortcut to focus on an object.  The perfect example of what I am talking about would be if you are moving a camera and have it locked to view, the viewport will move with the camera when moving it further than your viewport displays.  How can you do that but with a vertex, face, edge, object, etc?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186976/how-to-follow-object-when-moving?rq=1

Comment: There is no hotkey for such type of navigation. You can set Track To constraint to the camera and change the  object to track to. Then move it through the camera view. Tracking of selected vertices is also possible if you temporarily place them in a Vertex Group. Then add that vertex group in the Track To constraint. Now the Camera will track the vertices of the group when you move them. You just have to learn the hotkeys for adding and removing vertices from the active vertex group.

Comment: @josh sanfelici this will work for a specific object but if i have a bunch of objects joined together then it wont allow me to "track" or have the viewport move with a selected group of vertices of that object, it will be locked to the object in general i guess you would say.  thank you for your answer, i appreciate the help!!

Comment: @Rumen Belev - thank you, after spending quite some time combing through all of the menus and options this was the conclusion that i had came to, you have just confirmed that for me!!! thank you so much!!!